# mysql copy function/procedure between databases using only SQL

Tags: mysql, function, procedure

is it possible to copy functions and procedures between DBs without using any external program (e.g. mysqldump)? I am looking for something like

```
SELECT CREATE FUNCTION my_function INTO OUTFILE
```

As far as I can see at the moment the only way is using SHOW CREATE FUNCTION *my_function* and then parse the CREATE FUNCTION column.

Any hints much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use

```
SELECT * FROM `mysql`.`proc`
```

concat desired data from there and create your queries to reproduce you functions and procedures